# Reliably avoiding legend overlapping other elements in matplotlib pie chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pie-chart, legend-properties

I'm making a series of pie charts, and I'm looking for a way to automatically place the legend to avoid overlapping other elements (not just a manual intervention for each individual plot). For example:

```
fake_df = pd.DataFrame([70, 15, 15],
                   columns=['category'],
                   index=['Category Name 1', 'Category Name 2', 'Category Name 3'])
fake_df.plot.pie(y='category',
                 labels=None, 
                 autopct="%1.0f%%",
                 pctdistance=1.2,
)
```

[image]

I know that in this individual case I can explicitly assign the legend to 'upper left', or manually manipulate the placement of the legend or percentages in other ways to avoid the overlap, but that doesn't work for cases where the percentages show up in the upper left for example:

```
fake_df = pd.DataFrame([71, 15, 14],
                       columns=['category'],
                       index=['Category Name 1', 'Category Name 2', 'Category Name 3'])
fake_df.plot.pie(y='category',
                 labels=None, 
                 autopct="%1.0f%%",
                 pctdistance=1.2,
)
plt.legend(['Category Name 1', 'Category Name 2', 'Category Name 3'], loc='upper left')
```

[image]
And since I'm automatically making a large amount of pie charts where there isn't a single legend placement that will always work and I can't know where the potential overlaps will be, I want a general solution that reliably places the legend such that it avoids the overlap. Is this possible?

Comment: If you have enough percent values/sections of the pie, wouldn't they be impossible to avoid? Seems like assigning more space to the chart as needed is required. Otherwise the solution is just working in certain cases and fails in others.

Comment: You're right. In my particular case, there are only 3 categories so there will always be at least one corner that doesn't overlap the percentages, but more generally it's probably better to just put the legend further away so that it can never overlap no matter what. And that's what both answers so far have proposed.

(Though it's interesting that there doesn't seem to be a solution that makes a best effort to automatically avoid legend overlaps with plot elements.)

Answer (score 1):

```
fake_df = pd.DataFrame([70, 15, 15],
                   columns=['category'],
                   index=['Category Name 1', 'Category Name 2', 'Category Name 3'])

ax = fake_df.plot.pie(y='category',
                 labels=None, 
                 autopct="%1.0f%%",
                 pctdistance=1.2,
)

plt.legend(labels=fake_df.index, bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc='upper left')
```

**EDIT AFTER YOU HAVE UPDATED YOUR ANSWER WITH PARTIAL OF THE ABOVE CODE:**
You also need to use bbox_to_anchor parameter so that the legends placement does not overlap with the plot.

**bbox_to_anchor** : parameter tells matplotlib how to postion the legend relative to the anchor point.(bbox_to_anchor argument allows arbitrary placement of the legend)

**loc** : parameter tells matplotlib which corner of the legend should align with the anchor point

If you dont spesify the loc argument it will take the default value of "best" which makes matplotlib determine the location itself. By assigning the value of "upper left" to that parameter you are telling matplotlib which corner of the legend box should allign with the anchor point.

From documents https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html
:

[image]

Comment: Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. And to @ordinary_python_programmer's comment above, it's probably best to just place the legend outside the pie chart's space entirely, which is what you're doing here.

One question about this specifically -- it looks like when I don't include `loc='upper left'`, this doesn't actually place the legend outside the chart area. Is there a reason that including the `loc` argument is necessary when using `bbox_to_anchor`?

Comment: @BenP , I have made an edit to include answer to your new question.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably place each pandas pie chart in a matplotlib figure, setting the `legend` argument of the chart to `None`, while creating a figure legend like this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()
fake_df = pd.DataFrame([71, 15, 14],
                       columns=['category'],
                       index=['Category Name 1', 'Category Name 2', 'Category Name 3'])
fake_df.plot.pie(y='category',
                 labels=None,
                 legend=None,
                 autopct="%1.0f%%",
                 pctdistance=1.2,
                 ax=ax
)
fig.legend(labels=fake_df.index)

plt.show()
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, and as @ordinary_python_programmer suggested above, this is placing the legend outside the chart space entirely to avoid any possible overlap.